# Error in SQL unknown column under where and $_REQUEST()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla

I am wondering why my code give error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;

My code which gave me problem is:

```
$query->select(array('Name'))
->from($db->quoteName('#__regions'))
->where($db->quoteName('Name').'='.$_REQUEST['name']);
```

Comment: Have you made sure `$_REQUEST['name']` actually has a value?

Comment: Yes i get value but i think problem in " or dots ?

Comment: It means exactly that ... you have an error in the SQL syntax.  The dots are fine, thats string concatenation. Pre append `$ouput =` to that line of code and print it out (if possible, I'm not familiar with Joomla). Googling shows you can try this to print the SQL: `echo($query->__toString());` ... Paste the output into your question.

Comment: You might need to change `$_REQUEST['name']` to  `$db->quote($_REQUEST['name'])`

Comment: Thank you so solve my problem.